# Grails : how to change site favicon?

Tags: grails, favicon

I tried to replace `favicon.ico` in `/web-app/images/` folder but it doesn't work : my site still has the usual Grails favicon. What do I need to do more?

Comment: 1 : clean the project , it should do the trick , if not search the project where it has any other favicon.ico file which it is refering

Comment: Exactly: start in the root of your project and do `find . -name favicon.ico` and swap the new favicon out for the old one inside any directories that turn up in the results.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try to change `views\layout\main.gsp`

```
<html>  
    <head>  
        <title><g:layoutTitle default="Grails" /></title>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="${createLinkTo(dir:'css',file:'main.css')}" />  
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="${createLinkTo(dir:'images',file:'favicon.ico')}" type="image/x-icon" />  
        <g:layoutHead />  
        <g:javascript library="application" />                  
    </head>  
    <body>  
        <div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display:none;">  
            <img src="${createLinkTo(dir:'images',file:'spinner.gif')}" alt="Spinner" />  
        </div>      
        <div class="logo"><img src="${createLinkTo(dir:'images',file:'grails_logo.jpg')}" alt="Grails" /></div>     
        <g:layoutBody />        
    </body>     
</html>
```

and comment

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="${createLinkTo(dir:'images',file:'favicon.ico')}" type="image/x-icon" />
```

or clean your browser's cache. ;-)

Comment: Works in Chrome and FF, damn IE9 is not showing it.

Answer (score 5):

With the grails assets plugin you must use:

```
<head>
    ...
    <asset:link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
</head>
```

Answer (score 3):

Put `favicon.ico` file to `PROJECT/grails-app/assets/` folder,

add to UrlMappints

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
      ......
      "/favicon.ico"  (uri: "/assets/favicon.ico")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your icon file in this path:

```
grails-app\assets\images\favicon.ico
```

Then add this to the head element of your html:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/favicon.ico">
```